# Installing Neo4j on CENTOS 6.7?

Tags: neo4j, centos

I have installed Neo4j by the following steps:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key
sudo rpm --import neotechnology.gpg.key
```

then create neo4j.repo file :

```
[neo4j] 
name=Neo4j Yum Repo 
baseurl=http://yum.neo4j.org 
enabled=1 
gpgcheck=1
```

move it into:

```
sudo cp neo4j.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
```

Finally running the command to install neo4j

```
sudo yum install neo4j
```

But, it failed to start! and gave this Exception:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@621a8172' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:193)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from http://yum.neo4j.org:

> This is experimental and not considered safe for production. You have been warned.

Go to http://www.neo4j.com/download, grab the `tar.gz` and go from there.

BTW: Treating rpm as first class citizen is on the roadmap.